# Front Camera of Camera Plugin is not working properly in Ionic 3

Tags: angularjs, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

**Ionic 3 Camera Accessing Code**

```
 takePhoto(flag) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var sourceType: any;
  if (flag == "PHOTOLIBRARY") {
    sourceType = this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
  } else {
    sourceType = this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
  }
  const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 50,
    sourceType: sourceType,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    targetWidth: 450,
    targetHeight: 450,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
    correctOrientation: true,
    cameraDirection: this.camera.Direction.FRONT
  };
  this.camera.getPicture(options).then(
    imageData => {
      resolve(imageData);
    })

})
```

}

**While using Back camera it is working but when we change the cameraDirection of CameraOptions but still opens back camera **

Answer (score 0):

You can directly set 
cameraDirection: 1

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug which has been reported to Ionic 3's team. As of now, there is no possible way  to get front camera onclick for the issue. 
In the plugin's description they say,

> Any cameraDirection value results in a back-facing photo.

As a workaround, you can as user to click on button located at the left side of your screen to flip the camera.